# Avoid callin automatically grub-install when installing GRUB

Tags: grub2, apt, software-installation

Somehow when installing grub for Ubuntu in this way:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y --force-yes install grub
```

`grub-install` is called automatically and that procedure prompts the user for the device where to install GRUB.

I want to call `grub-install` manually without being prompt. Is there any way to do this?
Alternatively, is there any way to specify the device in which GRUB is going to be installed without being prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preseed the grub device option using:

```
echo "grub-pc   grub-pc/install_devices multiselect /dev/disk/by-id/DISKID" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

This will set the grub selection in the grub-pc package which is the one that calls the debconf prompt.